# Why does my first nextLine() get skipped?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Sitting with a school project and I am really confused.
My first nextLine(); in both my for loops gets skipped. I do not seem to understand why, i get this answer might be basic but i really cannot grasp this!

```
    for (int i = 0; i < antal; i++) {

        System.out.println("Name of the customer?");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        Kunde.setName(name);

        System.out.println("Adress of the customer?");
        String adresse = sc.nextLine();
        Kunde.setAdress(adresse);

        System.out.println("Mail of the customer?");
        String mail = sc.nextLine();
        Kunde.setMail(mail);

        System.out.println("Phone number of the customer?");
        int tlf = sc.nextInt();
        Kunde.setTlf(tlf);

        System.out.println("Postal code of the customer?");
        int postalcode = sc.nextInt();
        Kunde.setPostalCode(postalcode);

        int x = ran.nextInt(100000);
        Kunde.setOrderNumber(x);

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < antal; i++) {
        System.out.println("Any specific orderdetails revolving order " + Kunde.getName(i)
        + " If not, press enter");
        String details = sc.nextLine();
        order.add(details);

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "gets skipped"? Do you mean that in your second for loop, when you print "Any specific orderdetails..." and call `Kunde.getName(i)` the value is not set? You might need to edit your question to include the code for `Kunde`, because it seems odd that you `set` a single value, but then are `get`ting something with an index (`i`). The `sc.nextLine()` code looks fine, so I'm guessing it's something about how you're retrieving the value from `Kunde`.

Comment: The "name of the customer" and the "adress of the customer gets printed simultaneously, without anything being prompted from the nextLine() method.

Comment: That doesn't sound right - there must be something funky with how your scanner is set up. Can you edit your post to include that code as well? Does it work as you expect for the "Mail of the customer?" block? Where is your scanner reading from? Is it from standard input, or a file, or something? It seems like it's somehow starting with a blank line. What happens if you add `System.out.println("Name is: " + name)` on the line immediately after `String name = sc.nextLine()`?

Answer (score -1):

Scanner.nextInt method does not consume the last newline character of your input.
That's probably why the second loop's first nextLine is skipped.
Maybe you have a similar cas right before the first for as well?

Comment: The "name of the customer" and the "adress of the customer" gets printed simultaneously. So the nextLine(); takes it as a empty String.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question - although it might cause odd things to happen between iterations of the loop, the OP is asking about the *first* time the `nextLine()` method is called, so this won't be an issue at that point.